# Photoshop picks up input before AHK

Tags: autohotkey

Few years ago a have write following script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Photoshop
#Wheelup::
Send, {vkDD}
return
#IfWinActive ahk_class Photoshop
#WheelDown::
Send, {vkDB}
return
```

This script generate input '[' or ']' when I wheel mouse up or down while win-key is pressed. This script worked good, but now, when I have installed photoshop 2020, it's not working. I thought that ahk_class has been changed , but it's not the case. When I removed ifWinActive line, the script sent characters to the notepad, but not sent them to the photoshop. In addition, my other bingings, are not working while Photoshop is active too.
What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Photoshop  is running with admin privileges, then AHK won't intercept the key presses, and that could very well be the reason behind this problem.

If that is the case, try to run the AHK script as administrator by adding this to the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of the script):

```
; If the script is not elevated, relaunch as administrator and kill current instance:

full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
    try ; leads to having the script re-launching itself as administrator
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}
```

For more details read https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs.

Comment: Thank you, that's the case!