# Scrivener seems to be capturing keystrokes before AHK and thus breaking my script

Tags: autohotkey

I've never noticed another application doing this but my hotkeys don't work in scrivener. Ctrl D, the scrivener hotkey overwrites me own (make new card vs insert MM-DD). And other hotkeys it just seems to eat (windows arrow keys, for example, so I can't move the scrivener window around).

Thoughts?

This is the top of my my script just if you are curious:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
Run C:\Users\xxx\Documents\windowpad.ahk
Coordmode, Mouse, Screen
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
```

Comment: Try to run the script this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59488355/3419297

Comment: You could also try to use `#UseHook`, #InstallKeybdHook is not always enough.